# My position:fixed header disappears

Tags: html, css

So [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWhB0.png)'s my HTML code, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SNjr.png)'s the CSS. It's quite short.
My problem is that whenever I set my header (it's a div) to position:fixed it disappears, even when I set

```
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
```

If anyone can help, searching has provided little help on this one. Thanks a lot!

PS: What is going on with this website's text formatting? I need to write <'br/'> to jump to the next line wtf? But then commenting it out in html doesn't work. BTW that's the reason the code is in two pictures and not beautifully embed or whatever. Sorry for that.

Comment: I would highly recommend using the code snippet creator in stack overflow instead of linking to your code. It makes it much easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: Yes, wtf indeed - when you post a new question, there's a box in the right sidebar titled "How to Format" with the essential basics you need to know, plus a link to [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  
}
.left{
  float: left;
  height: 800px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  height: 800px;
  width: 89.5%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test the geader shit</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='header'>fixed header</div>
    <div class='left'>left shit</div>
    <div class='right'>right shit</div>
    <div id='footer'>footer</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When we make an element position fixed, we need to mention width , in your link i dont see u have mentioned any width to the #header element and also in html there is no text or content inside the

If you mention width it will appear. 100% width makes it full width as of browser's viewport

Comment: you need to give some width to the #header, give 100% to the #header and see

Answer (score 0):

Your header hasn't disappeared, it's just behind your two floating elements. Move the `<div id="header">` code below the floating divs.

Z-index only works with elements of the same position value which is why that isn't working for you.

That said, depending on what you're trying to achieve, I may avoid the floats and look at flexbox layouts instead.

Comment: _"Z-index only works with elements of the same position value"_ - not true; z-index works on positioned elements only - that means anything with a position value other than the default `static`. There's other stuff to be aware of though - see the excellent article [What No One Told You About Z-Index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your header div a width. When a div is empty and is not given a width and height it is basically invisible.

Comment: Okay that did it! Thank you very much!